# synchronized method called by swingWorker interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j, synchronized

I have a synchronized function that is initiated in a new thread from a loop in another function and there are many many calls to it. So I have:

```
foo(){
new SwingWorker() {
                @Override
                public void doInBackground() {
                    sync_foo();
                }
            }.execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("", e);
        }
}
```

`sync_foo` is defined as:

```
private synchronized void sync_foo() {
}
```

I put some debug lines in `sync_foo` to check if it is working as I expected. so I had:

```
private synchronized void sync_foo() {
    final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
    log.info("start");
    ...
    log.info("finish");
}
```

The logger here is Log4J which I understand is indeed thread-safe. I noticed that in the logfiles I sometimes have two subsequent "start". So I added a further line near the end `log.info("still alive")` and kept putting it nearer and nearer to `log.info("start");` to see if I ever stop getting double `starts` and always get `still alive` between the two, but I was still getting it and finally I resorted to putting it on the next line to `log.info("start");`:

```
private synchronized void sync_foo() {
    final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
    log.info("start");
    log.info("still alive");
    ...
    log.info("finish");
}
```

but every now and then, I still get:

```
start
start
```

which i find very puzzling. It appears that the method is somehow interrupted but I can't understand how. I should add that `sync_foo()` is only called from `foo()` and I am not getting any exception or error of any kind.

So the question is:

- In general, what are the possible causes of a method being interrupted by itself?
- I understand that Swing worker might have its own ways of handling threads execution. The SwingWorker that i use above, is in fact overridden and it's defined as in [here](http://pastebin.com/ddADtCiU). Is there anything in this extension that makes it possible to miss the relevant exceptions?

Comment: can you confirm that every time sync_foo is getting called for the same object and the object is not created every time ?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question text. We don't all have access to pastebin.

Comment: @NathanHughes sure. It's just that I had trouble with the formatting and it was annoying me.

Comment: @coder It is indeed on the same object. Actually I had initially written it with a static ReentrantLock, without the routine being declared synchronized and was getting the somewhat similar results. I resorted to the good old synchronized thinking that would get rid of the problem, but it didnt'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronization depends on sharing a lock, so if you see behavior where multiple threads are calling something that's synchronized concurrently, it means they're not using the same lock. It sounds like sync_foo is called on different objects. Using `synchronized` on the method means that the monitor on the object instance is acquired by a thread that wants to enter the method, so if the method is called on different objects there's no shared lock and nothing stopping a thread from entering the method on one object while another thread is executing the method on a different object.

You could make a class-level lock like this:

```
public static final Object LOCK = new Object();
```

and change your method to

```
private void sync_foo() {
    synchronized(LOCK) {
        final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
        log.info("start");
        log.info("still alive");
        ...
        log.info("finish");
    }
}
```

so all the objects that sync_foo is called on will use the same lock regardless of what instance it's called on.

Comment: As an alternative one could create a `LOCK` object in the main method (or another suitable position) and pass it from method call to method call. Using `static` could be avoided and the code might get better reusable.

Comment: @slartidan: agreed, using static is not the greatest, just hard to know where to put it without more information.

Comment: @NathanHughes Actually I originally wrote it just as you have written it above. I used a static `ReentrantLock` and was getting similar results. Which is why I switched to synchronized, thinking I might not have understood locks correctly, so I don't think it's a multi-threading issue and it kinda looks like the threads are actually being interrupted.

Comment: weird. I put two counter variables one incremented in `foo()` before calling `sync_foo()` and one incremented in `sync_foo()` at the end. To my surprise, they were almost in sync when all the calls were almost finished. This is not the impression you get when you look at the log files though. There are way more `"start"`s than there are `"finish"`es. It's like 2:1 or even 3:1. So, it looks like logger doesn't log many of the `log.info("finish");` messages. Why could this be?

Comment: btw, my `log.info("start");` were in fact `log.error("start");` as I have configured Intellij to show them in different colours. What should conclude from this behaviour? that logger has different qeues for `error()` and `info()` which are not synced with each other?

Comment: what appender are you using with log4j? if you have a different appender for errors, so one writes to stderr and the other writes to stdout, then those won't be synched up.